# spark mllib image classification python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, random-forest, apache-spark-ml

I'm new with Apache Spark and hadoop. 
I want to classify remote sensing images using spark.
I'm trying to use spark mllib random forest classifier using the documentation of spark mllib but i'm getting an error this is my code

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier
from pyspark.ml.feature import IndexToString, StringIndexer, 
VectorIndexer
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
data = 
spark.read.format("libsvm").load("data/mllib/images/multi-channel/image_sat.jpg")
```

this is the error message

> > 2018-06-17 16:01:34 WARN  LibSVMFileFormat:66 - 'numFeatures' option not specified, determining the number of features by going though the input. If you know the number in advance, please specify it via 'numFeatures' option to avoid the extra scan.
> >         2018-06-17 16:01:48 WARN  ObjectStore:568 - Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
> >         [Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 1]2018-06-17 16:01:55 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
> >         java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 63
> >             at org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.numBytesForFirstByte(UTF8String.java:191)
> >             at org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.numChars(UTF8String.java:206)
> >             at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
> >             at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
> >             at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
> >             at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
> >             at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
> >             at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
> >             at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
> >             at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:1014)
> >             at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:1013)
> >             at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:2123)
> >             at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:2123)
> >             at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
> >             at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
> >             at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
> >             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> >             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> >             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> >         2018-06-17 16:01:55 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 63
> >             at org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.numBytesForFirstByte(UTF8String.java:191)
> >             at org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.numChars(UTF8String.java:206)
> >             at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
> >             at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
> >             at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
> >             at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
> >             at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
> >             at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
> >             at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
> >             at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:1014)
> >             at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:1013)
> >             at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:2123)
> >             at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:2123)
> >             at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
> >             at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
> >             at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
> >             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> >             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> >             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> >         2018-06-17 16:01:55 ERROR TaskSetManager:70 - Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
> >         Traceback (most recent call last):
> >           File "", line 1, in 
> >           File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 166, in load
> >             return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))
> >           File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1160, in **call**
> >           File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
> >             return f(*a, **kw)
> >           File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 320, in get_return_value
> >         py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o57.load.
> >         : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 63
> >             at org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.numBytesForFirstByte(UTF8String.java:191)
> >             at org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.numChars(UTF8String.java:206)
> >             at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
> >             at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
> >             at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
> >             at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
> >             at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
> >             at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
> >             at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
> >             at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:1014)
> >             at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:1013)
> >             at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:2123)
> >             at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:2123)
> >             at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
> >             at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
> >             at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
> >             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> >             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> >             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

```
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1587)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1820)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1769)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1758)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2027)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2124)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1.apply(RDD.scala:1029)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.reduce(RDD.scala:1011)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils$.computeNumFeatures(MLUtils.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.source.libsvm.LibSVMFileFormat$$anonfun$1.apply$mcI$sp(LibSVMRelation.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.source.libsvm.LibSVMFileFormat$$anonfun$1.apply(LibSVMRelation.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.source.libsvm.LibSVMFileFormat$$anonfun$1.apply(LibSVMRelation.scala:95)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.source.libsvm.LibSVMFileFormat.inferSchema(LibSVMRelation.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$8.apply(DataSource.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$8.apply(DataSource.scala:202)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 63
    at org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.numBytesForFirstByte(UTF8String.java:191)
    at org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.numChars(UTF8String.java:206)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:1014)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:1013)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:2123)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:2123)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

I'm using python and ubuntu 16.04 
Someone can help me pleaaaaase

Thanks

Comment: Why you passing image inside load function?

Comment: what should I do instead of this !

Comment: First convert your image to feature vector and use those feature in spark

Comment: hi, i extracted feautres and now how can I use them in spark